# JSON.NET for .NETCF 2.0

Tags: compact-framework, json.net

Anyone having JSON builer/parser for .NETCF (Compact Framework) 2.0 version?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://jsoncf.codeplex.com/) library that works well with Compact Framework 2.0. This is not as mature as json.net but I have added Null attribute handling and JSONProperty for alias to actual field.